# ¿por qué mi código me da un ciclo infinito?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucles, revisión-de-código

es que en mi código deseo que el usuario decida la opción que desea ver. El problema es que si coloco algo incorrecto en "decision" me sale un ciclo infinito de "Decision incorrecta". No entiendo por qué sucede esto

```
decision=input("¿Desea ver la matriz de estadisticas modificada o solo la columna calculada? \n Responda 'estadisticas' o 'columna' dependiendo de su decision ")
terminado=False
while terminado==False:
    if decision=="estadisticas":
            terminado=True
            print("La matriz_modificada es {}".format(matriz_modificada))
    elif decision=="columna":
            terminado=True
            print("La columna calculada de autocubrimiento para cada facultad es {}".format(columna))
    else:
        print("Decision incorrecta")
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Que debería hacer si es incorrecta? ¿Volver a pedirla al usuario hasta que lo sea?

Comment: Seria algo arcaico, pero te recomiendo colocarle un `break` al fina del tu código, para que finalice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un ciclo infinito porque la variable de control del ciclo `terminado` **no se modifica si se cae el el `else`**, además como `decision` tampoco se modifica dentro del ciclo, los dos primeros condicionales jamás se cumplirán si en la primera iteración no lo hicieron, por lo que una vez ejecutado el `while` jamás se saldrá de el si decisión no es "estadisticas" o "columna".

Si quieres que se vuelva a pedir la opción  hasta que ingrese algo correcto, debes pedir el `input` dentro del `while`, dándo así la oportunidad de que decisión cambie, se caiga en el `if` o el `elif` y a su vez terminado cambie permitiendo la ruptura del ciclo:

```
terminado = False
while not terminado:
    decision = input((
        "¿Desea ver la matriz de estadisticas modificada "
        "o solo la columna calculada? \n "
        "Responda 'estadisticas' o 'columna' dependiendo de su decision "
         ))
    if decision == "estadisticas":
            terminado = True
            print("La matriz_modificada es {}".format(matriz_modificada))
    elif decision == "columna":
            terminado = True
            print((
                "La columna calculada de autocubrimiento "
                "para cada facultad es {}").format(columna)
                 )
    else:
        print("Decision incorrecta")
```

Si no quieres volver a pedirlo, entonces simplemente el ciclo sobra:

```
decision = input((
    "¿Desea ver la matriz de estadisticas modificada "
    "o solo la columna calculada? \n "
    "Responda 'estadisticas' o 'columna' dependiendo de su decision "
    ))
if decision == "estadisticas":
    print("La matriz_modificada es {}".format(matriz_modificada))
elif decision == "columna":
    print((
        "La columna calculada de autocubrimiento "
        "para cada facultad es {}").format(columna)
         )
else:
    print("Decision incorrecta")
```

---

Aunque correcto en cuanto a sintaxis y funcionalmente, `while terminado==False:`  (o `if algo == True`, `algo != True`, etc) no es la forma correcta de comprobar si algo es evaluado como verdadero en Python, se debe usar if/while [not] algo:

- `while terminado == False` -> `while not terminado:`
- `if terminado != False / if terminado == True:` -> `if terminado:`
- `if terminado == False / if terminado != True:` -> `if not terminado:`

Si quieres saber si algo es el objeto `bool` `True`, que no es lo mismo que saber si algo se evalúa como verdadero, se debe usar el operador de identidad `is`/`is not`, dado que `True`/`False`/`None` son singletons:

```
if terminados is not True:
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu programa se queda en un loop infinito porque solo al principio le pides al usuario que elija una opcion, si el usuario no elige "columna" o "estadisticas" no entra ni al if ni al elif va al else y en el else no se le vuelve a preguntar al usuario que quiere, entonces sale del else y vuelve al bucle sin haber cambiado de decision y asi sucesivamente, esto se soluciona agregando esta linea al final en el else:

`decision=input("¿Desea ver la matriz de estadisticas modificada o solo la columna calculada? \n Responda 'estadisticas' o 'columna' dependiendo de su decision ")`